# Has the structure of the 2-dimensional pin$^{\pm}$ bordism categories been written down?

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, topological-quantum-field-theory, spin-geometry

If $H\to\mathrm O$ is a tangential structure (e.g. orientation, spin), let $\mathsf{Bord}_2^H$ denote the category whose objects are 1-dimensional manifolds with $H$-structure and whose morphisms $M_1\to M_2$ are diffeomorphism classes of bordisms from $M_1$ to $M_2$ with $H$-structure. This category is symmetric monoidal under disjoint union.

The structure of the oriented bordism category $\mathsf{Bord}_2^{\mathrm{SO}}$ is well-known, as part of the proof that a 2D oriented TQFT is equivalent to a Frobenius algebra. (Joachim Kock has [a good set of notes](http://mat.uab.es/~kock/TQFT/FS.pdf) on the subject.)

The structure of the spin bordism category was worked out by Moore and Segal in ["$D$-branes and $K$-theory in 2D topological field theory,"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0609042.pdf) and further discussed in [a paper of Gunningham](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.1273.pdf).

My question is: **have descriptions of the categories $\mathsf{Bord}_2^{\mathrm{Pin}^+}$ and $\mathsf{Bord}_2^{\mathrm{Pin}^-}$ been written down?**

I'm interested in particular in 2D extended TQFT, hence in the relevant bordism 2-categories, but a nonextended description would still be helpful.

Comment: As far as I know this has not appeared in the literature in either the extended or nonextended cases.